# Изолирование проектов PhpShtorm. Как настроить автозаполнение?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

Я работаю в PhpShtorm 2018.1 и у меня всегда открыто множество проектов на фреймворке Laravel. Проблема заключается в том, что при автозаполнении вызываемых классов PhpShtorm предлагает выбрать файл, например, из другого проекта?! Или же наоборот, при использовании классов предупреждает о множественном определении. В настройках ничего не нашел, может кто сталкивался с такими же трудностями.

Comment: Может дело в версии ? на 2020 такого не наблюдаю

Comment: Может они просто учли это в 2020, надо попробоваться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело не в версии. а в способе открытия проектов.

проекты открывать не в одном инстансе шторма,
а каждый проект свой инстанс.

тогда и не будет таких проблем.